# How to cache remote web resources for web page speeding?

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, seo

I use "google pagespeed insights" to get suggetion about my web site(php site). And one suggestion is “Use the browser cache stores the following cacheable resources:http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js”. I know how to make cache work for local resources(I use ifmodule mod_expires.c in .htaccess file). But How to do it when resoucres is a remote third party one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing things.

First, you don't control the browsers cache. The only thing you can do is tell the browser, through headers, that the resources YOU'RE serving CAN be cached. It's up to the browser to follow those instructions.

Secondly, remote resources are... well... remote! So you don't really control them. Of course you can proxy them through your server and add the appropriate cache control headers, but that kind of defeats the purpose of distributed delivery.

---

Now, usually to speed up PHP pages, you use some kind of SERVER-SIDE caching mechanism ([see the list on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators)). Server-side caching can work through a number of ways and is almost a requirement in any modern mid-sized php wwebsite.